# SQL Server reporting services scheduler loops, running amok

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2, Service Pack 1 with an SQL Server 2008 R2 (Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit), version 10.50.4042.0) for creating scheduled reports in SSRS. The Report Server services didn't start up after a server restart a while ago and when I noticed that after several days, I started the service. Then it began to loop thru all reports constantly, as if the server not was aware of that it had already done that report.

When I look in the table [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLogStorage] I can see that new reports are created constantly as fast as the previous report is ready. It looks to loop thru all reports.

I found two errors in Windows application log which maybe are connected to the problem, or not.

> Failed to unload app domain DefaultDomain.  The following exception occurred: Error while unloading appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015).
>
> ProcessName: ReportingServicesService
> ProcessId: 4308
> Failed to trace event: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.

I really don't understand what to do. The server has been running for several years, doing the scheduled jobs without any problem. I have restarted SQL Server Agent, Reporting Services as well as the whole server and it doesn't make any difference.

I am thankful for any help.

Lage

Comment: What do you mean by " loop thru all reports constantly"? Where do you see this happening? in logs? What do you mean by "new reports are created constantly"?

Comment: I am guessing, but it sounds like you ended up with a bunch of scheduled report events in the queue that is playing catch up since the service is now running. This is a guess because the SSRS instances I run will automatically start on boot, so I have not seen this first hand before. Another guess is that this will subside soon, if it hasn't already.

Comment: Thanks you for your comments. 

@Nick.McDermaid - With loop thru I mean that I have around 30 reports. They are scheduled to be sent every fourth hour to once per day. Now all 30 reports are sent one after another without any time between. When report No. 30 is sent it starts again with report No. 1 and so on in an infinite loop. I noticed it in my "report inbox" which was spammed with copies of these reports. I have some reports where a cc is sent to me.

Then I could find it in the ExecutionLogStorage table.

Comment: I want to say that it is the Event table in the SSRS database, but I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: @R.Richards, looks like an idea that it could be the queue. Do you know where I can find the queue? I saw this in the Windows log:


>Schedules, events, and subscriptions processing may be delayed because processing queue reached the maximum item count = 4. Items currently being processed: 
 #0, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.NotificationQueueItem
 #1, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.NotificationQueueItem
 #2, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.NotificationQueueItem
 #3, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.NotificationQueueItem."

But maximum item count = 4, so looks odd

Comment: @R.Richards, I think you are right in some way. Each time the job is running, a row is stored in that table. I searched for it and found that in a discussion on a social.msdn MS site. But they strongly recommended to not delete anything manually in a production environment. And there were only 12 rows in the table so it looks more like something not is updating when the report is executed. When I tried to start the reporting services service I got more than 100 repeated reports in my inbox in less than 20 minutes before I stopped the service. I will ask there too and tell here if I get answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from MS Developer Network, so want to share it here if someone get similar problems.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cd9f753-02b2-4dea-a77a-0fa33fe80c7a/sql-server-reporting-services-scheduler-in-infinite-loop-spamming-reports?forum=sqlreportingservices

Best regards

Lage